# Php/mysql Error

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

**Resolved** Thank you everyone! It turned out "Group" was a registered mysql term so I changed "Group" to Web_Group. Phew... This was frustrating me all night. Thank you so much stackoverflow users!

I keep trying to write to a column in mysql which is "Group" and it doesn't work.

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users SET username='$username',password='$pass',mcname='$mcname',Group='Member',email='$email',confirm='$confirmcode',status='0'");
```

The weird part is if I take out Group='Member' The code works flawlessly. Yes the column "group" starts with a capital letter so that isn't the problem.

What can I do to fix this?

The MySQL error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group='Member',email='sdfsdf',confirm='1d4ba9f5cbb214965b4f6ba5ad1c4fba',status=' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, I think the error is that your column name is `group` which is a reserved word. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

You could escape the column name with backticks: ` like this:

```
`Group`="Value"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up just changing "Group" to "Web_Group"

Comment: No worries - I always consult that table before creating DBs. It's funny that Type or Number are not reserved but Group is. This used to catch me out a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The word "Group" is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) so you need to add back-ticks (`) around the column name.

Try doing the following:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users SET username='$username',password='$pass',mcname='$mcname',`Group`='Member',email='$email',confirm='$confirmcode',status='0'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct systax if you wanna insert to your database table

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username,password,mcname,Group,email,confirm,status) VALUES('$username','$pass','$mcname','Member','$email','$confirmcode','0')");
```

Comment: Thanks for the INFO i never thought that mysql is not so case sensitive